# How to upload csv file which list data was written into, to the GCP

Tags: python-3.x, csv, google-cloud-platform, io, google-cloud-functions

I want to upload csv file which list data was written in, to the GCS by using cloud functions.
And I want to upload csv file as the character code, UTF-8.

Actually I could upload csv file which string data was written in, but I could not upload csv file which **list** data was written in.

The bellow code is for writing **string data** into csv file, which I could upload to GCS

【MAIN.PY】

```
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd
import io
import csv
from io import BytesIO 

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_file(source_file_name)

def upload_csvfile(data, context):
    try:
        object_name = data['name']
        bucket_name = data['bucket']

        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(object_name)

        message = "Data for CSV file"  
        with open('/tmp/test.csv', "w", encoding='cp932') as f: 
            f.write(message) 
        with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file_obj: 
            upload_blob('test_bucket', file_obj, 'csv_test1.csv')
    except Exception as e:
          print(e)
```

【REQUIREMENTS.TXT】

```
google-cloud-storage==1.30.0
gcsfs==0.6.2
pandas==1.1.0
```

And next bellow code is for writing **list** data into csv file, which I **could not** upload.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import csv
import codecs
from io import BytesIO 
from io import StringIO

#write list into csv file
def export_list_csv(export_list, csv_dir):
    with open(csv_dir, "w", encoding='cp932') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        if isinstance(export_list[0], list): #in case of multidimension
            writer.writerows(export_list)
        else:
            writer.writerow(export_list) # in case of single dimension

def upload_csvfile(data, context):
     try:
          object_name = data['name']
          bucket_name = data['bucket']
          storage_client = storage.Client()
          bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
          blob = bucket.blob(object_name)

          #message = [1,2,3, "apple", "りんご", "林檎"] # single dimension
          message = [[1,2,3], ["apple", "りんご", "林檎"]] # multidimension 
          with open('/tmp/test.csv', "w", encoding='cp932') as f: 
               writer = csv.writer(f)
               if isinstance(message[0], list): # for multidimension 
                    writer.writerows(message)
               else:                            # for single dimension
                    writer.writerow(message)
          with codecs.open("/tmp/test.csv", "r", "utf-8", "ignore") as file_obj: 
               print("file_obj.read():{0}".format(file_obj.read())) 

               #upload csv file as 'csv_test1.csv' to 'test_bucket'
               storage_client = storage.Client()
               bucket4 = storage_client.get_bucket('test_bucket')
               blob4 = bucket4.blob('csv_test1.csv')
               blob4.upload_from_file(file_obj)

     except Exception as e:
          print("error:{}".format(e))
```

And I got this error.

```
Stream must be at beginning
```

Then I fix code like bellow.

```
            #message = [1,2,3, "apple", "りんご", "林檎"] # single dimension
            message = [[1,2,3], ["apple", "りんご", "林檎"]] # multidimension 
            with open('/tmp/test.csv', "w", encoding='cp932') as f: 
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                if isinstance(message[0], list): # for multidimension 
                    writer.writerows(message)
                else:                            # for single dimension
                    writer.writerow(message)

            with codecs.open("/tmp/test.csv", "r", "utf-8", "ignore") as file_obj:
                print("file_obj.read():{0}".format(file_obj.read())) 
                out_file = StringIO(file_obj.read())  # 1/2 I fix here

                #upload csv file as 'csv_test1.csv' to 'test_bucket'
                storage_client = storage.Client()
                bucket4 = storage_client.get_bucket('test_bucket')
                blob4 = bucket4.blob('csv_test1.csv')
                blob4.upload_from_file(out_file)    # 2/2 I fix here
```

Actually I **could** upload csv file to the GCS, but the csv file didn't have any data in itself. The csv file should have list data...

I don't have any idea to solve this issue and upload csv file in GCS.

Could anyone help me, please. Thank you.

Comment: Check [this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-resumable-media-python/issues/165). It might give you insights on how to overcome this.

Comment: Thank you for give me your help. 
But I could upload csv file but still it does not have any data...
How should I do...

Comment: Have you checked it `/tmp/test.csv` actually has data written before uploading it?